# How to Install Visual Studio 2015 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, visual-studio-2015

I have heard about Visual Studio . Net 2015 for Ubuntu 
I can't find anything useful online yet 
Can you please help me install this version on ubuntu linux? 

Thank you...

Comment: Visual Studio . Net 2015 for Ubuntu ? You can run asp.net vnext web apps under linux, but I don't think you can install visual studio 2015 on ubuntu

Comment: "have heard about" is never a question. You are the one who should get more info about that. Make sure you always get the full news, such as [Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com)

Comment: @LutzPrechelt - Don't tell people to delete their posts. If it's not in the right place, it will be deleted by the approval system.

Comment: I never have heard about that. Even not about older versions of VS.Net. I'd be greatly interested in such an installation of VS.Net on Linux! I'd even pay the price for the full licenses if I could get VS.Net running on our Linux boxes.

Comment: Why do you need VS on Linux? Use something native to Linux or do programming on Windows and compile on Linux if it's cross-platform code. If need .net it's the simplest way to use it on Linux, however, read what .net code supported on Mono or use .NET Core to run on Linux without any Mono install.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no Visual Studio can be run in the LINUX or UBUNTU version.It only can run in Windows

Answer (score 2):

You can try Wine, but per the Wine application database, Visual Studio generally works poorly under Wine 
use this link

```
 https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892
```

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) isn't an IDE like [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)

Instead, it's a modified version of [ATOM](https://atom.io/) which is a text editor. It lacks almost everything from the original Visual Studio. By now, Visual Studio 2015 isn't properly working under WinE. Maybe a test can be done using the ISO instead of the web installer. Make ISO installer work under WinE it's your only option to get Visual Studio under Linux.

Comment: The original poster is asking about Visual Studio 2015, not VSCode... I'd also like to know if it is possible to install Visual Studio IDE on linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wine, but it probably wont work very well.

Visual Studio Code isn't a full IDE and I hate it, but you can try it.

You could use a virtual machine with windows on it, or you could look at other programs that are similar. For example I use pycharm, because I generally work in python.

Comment: Visual Studio Code isn't an IDE at all. It's not supposed to be a cross platform replacement for the full fat Visual Studio. It's supposed to be a feature rich code editor, in line with things like Atom, Sublime, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wine.
Or Visual Studio Code, announced and released (preview) today:
https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have released a cut down version for Linux  https://code.visualstudio.com/ its simply called visual studio code! Then you have to install additional components such as ASP.NET version 5 which you can download from the same link. In my own experience I installed all of these and the program worked fine. That is until it was time to reboot my Linux Mint v 17.2 system. I use an encrypted drive and was able to enter my password to unencrypt my drive, but then after entering my userpassword my system crashed and went into a loop which I couldnt get out of. So I had to boot from a USB stick with Mint on it and unencrypt the drive from there to remove Visual Studio Code and its components just to access my system again so beware - there is a major bug here which needs fixing.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not an IDE it is a spruced up text editor.

Comment: It is an IDE. But not of that quality like Visual Studio.

Comment: @BigC: Visual Studio Code is not a "cut down" version. It is a completely different software.