# Does VSCode have built-in support or extensions available for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 and learning VB. I cannot find any extensions for VB.NET.

Is there an extension or would a Windows VM be a better option?

Comment: Interesting. I had a look and I couldn't find anything but according to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d38c8ae-70f3-4e2e-9a2a-89efda3cf578/does-vscode-support-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral) it must have done at some point. I also don't think it's relevant to the OS so a Windows VM wouldn't make a difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: you can't run VB.NET on Linux as far as I know, so possibly the extension isn't available for the Linux version of vscode. Would make some sense, as it'd be impossible to run a debugger or anything. So your choices are 1) use a windows VM, 2) learn C# instead, which runs on more platforms and is also more widely used generally.

Comment: @ADyson I couldn't see an extension anyway for VB.NET. I'm not familiar with the software so maybe I'm missing something. I didn't know that about Linux though. Why would C# be OK though?

Comment: @Bugs because C# is supported on Linux via both the .NET Core and Mono frameworks.

Comment: @ADyson interesting, I had no idea. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Bugs you're also right though, there doesn't appear to be a VB.NET plugin for VSCode of any kind, on any platform, which surprises me a little bit.

Comment: @Reimott correction to what I said above, running VSCode in Windows will not help you. But, with a VM, you _could_ run Visual Studio Community Edition instead (assuming you don't want to pay for Visual Studio). Personally, I'd go the C# route though because I think it has a better future, but it depends what you want/need to achieve.

Comment: According to that link I posted at the top it did at some point. I'm trying to find out if it's been removed but I can't see anything. The suggestion of VS community is what came to my mind.

Comment: @ADyson The [.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/06/the-week-in-net-on-net-with-brett-morrison-datetime-extensions/) shared a [third-party blog post I read today](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/06/dotnet-core-vbnet/) which suggests that VB.NET support is coming to .NET Core 2.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton well that's good news for VB.NET. I would assume a plugin for VSCode will follow at some later time. NET Core 2 isn't scheduled for release until autumn this year, and then presumably it would be a bit longer for a VSCode enhancements, so I guess it depends how patient Reimott wants to be.

Comment: I would consider a VM, but have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987283/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything on the Marketplace other than VBScript and VBA extensions:
[VS Marketplace: VB.NET extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=vb.net&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)
But since you are learning VB.NET I would suggest to download Visual Studio Community and play with it and develop an application. Then you're also learning the .NET environment.
I started the same with Forms applications, but now only use WPF, because it's a better option to design nicer GUIs.
If you really want to use VS Code then an VM or dual boot is your best bet.