# How to enable intellisense in Visual Studio 2017 for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I've just gotten started with programming in Unity. I installed Visual Studio Code 2017 recently on Zorin 12. It's a nice interface, but there's no auto-completion! I realize that Ctrl+Space pops up some suggestions, but there are two problems that I'd like resolved with this:

- The suggestions don't pop up automatically
- The suggestions are based on redundancies in code I've already typed, not suggestions based on unexplored capabilities of Unity. If I'm working with a Transform object, for example, I want it to pop up all of the possible variables I could use, not just the one I used earlier.

Two errors I get can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvEes.png

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: When you install VS2017 be sure to include the Unity3D features

Comment: @Isaac Thompson - if you are still having trouble with this after you’ve tried what I’ve outlined in my answer, please let me know, I’ll work through it with you.

Comment: Yep, still need help. Couldn't get monodevelop to work at all, so I'm sticking to VS for now. Some solutions to the problem say to go under the tools menu, to options, and change a text setting, however I can't find this in VS 2017, is it gone?

Comment: Two errors I have can be seen at https://i.imgur.com/AwHl4ef.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Windows or macOS:**

Download/Install the [Visual Studio IDE (with Unity Tools)](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/unity-tools/)

When installing, make sure you include installation of

> Game development with Unity

[image]

Then using Unity (you can double click one of your C# files), open a new C# project and the Visual Studio IDE should open with your new project structure.

[image]

From there, you should be able to see what you are looking for.

For example:

[image]

[image]

**For Linux (suggestion):**

Try [Monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin) - [Additional Information](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MonoDevelop.html), it provides code completion/hints.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice but this won't work on Linux. I attempted installing it via wine but was forbidden due to requirements. Any suggestions for Linux?

Comment: @IsaacThompson See if this post [How can I install Visual Studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio) helps you get there, looks to me like the answer of running a VM might work, but I dont know if you'd want to run Unity and Visual Studio in the VM.

Comment: @IsaacThompson I've updated my answer with a suggestion for Linux uses.

Comment: @IsaacThompson You might want to read this too for additional information, albeit its just information about how it isn't going to be possible: [How to install Visual Studio 2015 in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987283/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @IsaacThompson thank you!

Comment: No problem, after several attempts I got MonoDevelop working, which fixed the intellisense issues.

Comment: @IsaacThompson cool to hear, happy you got it working. Unity is an awesome engine