# How do I get autofill suggestions from unity in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am following a beginners' unity tutorial, and the guy I am watching has special colours for different types of text. (Orange for vars, blue for floats etc.) He also has autocomplete suggestions from unity, for example there's a function in the unity camera called ScreenToWorldPoint. When he was writing it out, he got an autocomplete suggestion to do it but I didn't. This is the same with all other unity-only functions.

The guy has his visual studio settings available for download, which I did so the problem isn't with that. I think it must be in the 'connection' between unity and vs.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Camera cam;
    Vector2 movement;
    Vector2 mousePos;
```

In the video, MonoBehaviour , Vector2 and UnityEngine are all coloured but in my version of vs they're not. Using, public and float are all highlighted as they should be though.
Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNLVOjbrQj4

Comment: Would help if you linked the video... also told us the version of visual studios...  also I believe there is a plugin in VS for unity.

Comment: i've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add [SOLVED] to the title or edit the solution into the question. If you've found a solution you'd like to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: In VS there should be an "extensions" tab on the left side of the editor. You can search in there for Unity / C# extensions

Comment: Can you share your solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get intellisense in Visual Studio Code for Unity functions names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189426/how-to-get-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code-for-unity-functions-names)