# IntelliSense in DOTS unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

SO I was following unity's own DOTS ping pong tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9AUXNFBWt4 where I noticed that I don't Have fully working IntelliSense inside my Entities.Foreach().

```
Let's take this as an example:
Entities.ForEach((ref PhysicsVelocity vel,in SpeedIncreaseOverTimeData data) => 
        {
            float2 modifier = new float2(data.increasePerSecond * deltaTime);

            float2 newVel = vel.Linear.xy;
            newVel += math.lerp(-modifier, modifier, math.sign(newVel));
        }).Run();
```

so here the IntelliSense makes it look like my variables are private and they don't show up in the list, but it works fine if I just type it out.

anyone know a way to fix this, really hard using Unity and all their premade structs if I can't quick see what variables I have to work with.

Comment: Does this help? The answer by Chris. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58265695/7563114

Answer (score 0):

If that is an IQueryable, that could be the issue. What happens if you do the following?

```
Entities.ToList().ForEach =>
```

Comment: I don't have acess to a .ToList() on Entities also in the video the guy has full acess to the public fields of his struct, but I don't, which is what i find weird